# Is there a list of lootable items for every mob?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know that we can loot BOE (Bind on Equip) on every mob in WoW.

Can I find a list of BOE lootable in the new extensions for example?

In dungeon, the list is already shown but I didn't find a list for the other mob.

Comment: What does LQE stand for?

Comment: LQE is the trench version of BWE (bind when equipped) which are those items that you can't trade anymore when equipped once.

Comment: You close-voting guys do realize that the dungeon list is an ingame menu and no off-site resource? This is no recommendation question. This is simply a question about loot tables and where to find them in the game (like the dungeon guide, which already does that for boss loot).

Comment: As it is this question isn't very clear. Do you mean you want to view the Dungeon Journal loot list for every other mob (normal, elite or boss) in the game world?

Comment: @IvoCoumans I'm trying to find a list for every other mob in the game world. I mean, are they already listed somewhere?

Comment: In-game you won't find many resources, but a site like Wowhead lists every lootable item for every single mob out there.

Answer (score 1):

A list of every item available from every mob does not exist in the game at this point in time.
You will have to use an external tool like wowhead to find this information.